OKTA SSO(Customizing error messages on OAUTH sign-in)
I created an OIDC - OpenID Connect web application on my Okta developer dashboard, after that, i set it up and integrated it to my web application.
Basically, users in my organizations can use the Okta integration to perform SSO on the web application as long as the users had been assigned to the OpenID app on Okta dashboard.
Now is their a way by which i can customize the error message a user sees when they try to sign in with invalid credentials. Cause i to customize the generic 'Unable to sign in' error message.
